# Characters displaying correctly in File Geodatabase with ArcMap 10.1 but incorrectly with 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes, file-geodatabase, font

I work with data from a variety of European countries, and am having trouble getting the non-standard characters (e.g. Turkish alphabet) to display correctly in my geodatabase tables.  Sure, i expected this, but when I was running ArcGIS 10.1, they all displayed just fine!  I tried the registry edit workaround suggested on the ESRI website, to no avail.  Anybody have any better suggestions for reverting all of my '?' characters to their correct letters?

And no, i have no idea which character set they came from originally, nor which coding system they should be using.. no idea at all.

Comment: ESRI uses the standard fonts installed with windows so unless a font has been removed it should all be OK. Have you tried the Advanced System Settings Utility (Admin required) http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000300000018000000.htm when you open the table the appearance drop down allows you to change the font, for 10.1 the font is Arial.

Comment: Thank you -- I've tried editing the registry to support UTF-8 for shapefiles (which also failed), but this issue is more frustrating, since the EXACT SAME FGDB feature class displayed perfectly in 10.1, but not 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run both ArcGIS 10.1 and 10.2 on the same machine so it's **likely a missing font issue.** rather than a problem with the newer version. (Missing, corrupt or conflicting fonts.)

Remove all fonts from the 10.2 machine and try again. (default windows fonts are protected and will not be removed) If this did not correct the problem, copy all fonts from the machine that does work (in your case the one that runs 10.1) and install on the 10.2 machine.

Please note that ArcMap slows down considerably (dialog boxes, labelling, etc.) with too many installed fonts. If you use ArcMap frequently for cartography work it is a good idea to have the absolute bare minimum of fonts installed.